# Converting jquery lightbox to user tagged gallery additions

Tags: jquery

I have a question about how to rewrite a lightbox script that uses jquery.

Its using div ids to differentiate galleries. I'd like to have it use the `rel=""` attribute, with perhaps a trailing number. Can this be written to check for something such as `rel="gallery1"` but within a loop that increments the number? I'm unfamiliar with the js syntax for such things. Or perhaps a loop with checks the dom for objects with that rel. Thx.

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $('#gallery1 a').lightBox();
    $('#gallery2 a').lightBox();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop through a for loop 3 times calling `.lightBox()` on links with `rel` of `gallery1`, `gallery2` and `gallery3`. You can increase the loop number to however many you want.

**Javascript**

```
for (x = 1; x <= 3; x += 1) {
    $('a[@rel*=gallery' + x + ']').lightBox();
}​
```

Although I think you can group lightboxes just by specifying different `rel` properties and calling `.lightBox()` on all the links.

Give all your lightbox links a class of `lightbox` and then specify different `rel` groups such as `gallery1`, `gallery2` and `gallery3` for all the links. Then call the following, I think `.lightBox()` and they should all be grouped seperately.

**HTML**

```
<a href="[image_src]" class="lightbox" rel="gallery1">[link text or thumbnail]</a>
<a href="[image_src]" class="lightbox" rel="gallery1">[link text or thumbnail]</a>
<a href="[image_src]" class="lightbox" rel="gallery1">[link text or thumbnail]</a>

<a href="[image_src]" class="lightbox" rel="gallery2">[link text or thumbnail]</a>
<a href="[image_src]" class="lightbox" rel="gallery2">[link text or thumbnail]</a>

<a href="[image_src]" class="lightbox" rel="gallery3">[link text or thumbnail]</a>
<a href="[image_src]" class="lightbox" rel="gallery3">[link text or thumbnail]</a>
<a href="[image_src]" class="lightbox" rel="gallery3">[link text or thumbnail]</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('a.lightbox').lightBox();
```

What should happen is `gallery1` links group together, the `gallery2` links group together and the `gallery3` links group together. This should happen by default.

I hope this helps.

**Edit 1**

Something to note, the jQuery lightbox plugin has not been updated for 4.5 years. You may want to look at a better maintained alternative like [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox).